# RPi-Cam-Web-Interface - Problem Loading Page when IP Address is entered

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, webcam

I have spent most of the day trying to install RPi-Cam-Web-Interface onto my device with no success. I have followed the instructions [here](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) but once the installer has finished (using the defaults) I am unable to access the camera via the URL on neither a network computer or the device itself. I used the http:\ipAddress\html and also http:\ipAddress with no success. It simply states there was a problem loading page.

The red light on the camera switches on, so it seems to be working but I have no idea how to access the live feed from the device using the IP address. The installation notes in the above link mentions something about editing a document in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rpicam but this location does not exist on my pi.

Is this a known issue and if so is there anything I can try to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seemed there was an error when it tried to install using the default Apache settings.

I solved the problem by changing the installation to nginx and the port from o80 to 80.